# Allow stream operator on derived classes

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I have an interface that boils down to

```
class interface
{
    protected:
        virtual void write(std::string const &) = 0;
};
```

And derived classes like

```
class derived : public interface
{
    protected:
        void write(std::string const & buf) 
        { 
            std::cout << buf << std::endl; 
        }
};
```

In my application, these objects are passed around as smart pointers, i.e. `std::shared_ptr<derived>`. I hoped I could overload the `<<` operator, but only for smart pointer of derivatives of my interface. I tried this:

```
class interface
{
    /* ... */
    private:
        template <typename Derived> friend typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_base_of<interface, Derived>::value,
            std::shared_ptr<Derived>
        >::type & operator<<(std::shared_ptr<Derived> & lhs,
                std::string const & rhs)
        {
            lhs->write(rhs);
            return lhs;
        }
};
```

But when I try `std::shared_ptr<derived> sp; sp << "test";`, the compiler complains that `virtual void derived::write(const string&) is protected within this context` (`this context` is my friend function).

Is there a way to achieve this without redundantly writing a stream operator for every derived class?

Comment: Any reason why `write` is `protected`? From what you posted it only has side-effects, so there is no reason to hide it from the user. In particular since the user is anyway able to observe all of those side-effects through the ostream inserter.

Comment: Since `write` is virtual and in the operator body `lhs` contains a `Derived*` which is convertible to `interface*` you can "upcast" (not the `shared_ptr` reference directly, but the underlying pointer): http://ideone.com/lqZ2o8 (but as said @user2362671 you can use `std::shared_ptr<interface> sp(new derived)` instead)

Comment: @ComicSansMS I wanted to keep the public API as clean as possible, and gx_'s solution seems to allow  me exactly that, or is there any drawback of that solution I am not seeing?

Comment: I would question the idea of overloading the stream operator for a smart pointer in the first place. It's a pointer and operators invoked on it are not supposed to dereference it (apart from the dereferncing operators ;)). If your objects are referenced through pointers then it is just natural to dereference them when calling any operators as `*ptr << "whatever"` instead of `ptr << "whatever"`, in the same way as you call member functions using `->` instead of `.`. You don't expect `shared_ptr<int> one = make_shared(1); one + 3;` to return `4` either, do you?

Comment: @ChristianRau If I understand what he's trying to do correction, what he wants is more the equivalent of `*ptr << "xxx"`; the object is the left hand operator of the `<<`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah, realized this and changed the comment, though the reasoning still holds, I think.

Comment: @ChristianRau I agree with the reasoning.  If I have a pointer (smart or otherwise), I expect different semantics than if I have an object; I do _not_ expect the pointer to behave as if it were the object.

Comment: @ChristianRau You're right - that's actually a point that might lead to confusion/unexpected behavior, I guess I will limit the operator to the class not, the pointer of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply define your operator as:

```
friend std::shared_ptr<interface> &operator<<(std::shared_ptr<interface> & lhs, std::string const & rhs);
```

and pass your objects as `std::shared_ptr<interface>`?

Comment: I thought about that, but the existing codebase limits me to provide both options.

Comment: @user2573221 Why?  Are there functions in `derived` that you must call that aren't declared virtual in `base`?

Comment: There are functions in `derived` that are not declared at all in `base`