# Overloading << operator with polymorphism

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have read some similar questions and answers at SO, but don't really understand the answers there. My apologies, if this is a duplicate.

Have a base class like this.

```
class CParam
{
    public:
        virtual void PrintData(ostream &OutStream) = 0;
};
```

Now I inherit from this:

```
class CUInt32:public CParam
{
    public:
          void PrintData(ostream &OutStream);
}

void CUInt32::PrintData(ostream &OutStream)
{
    // Write some data to OutStream Here
}
```

I overload operator << for CUInt32 class

```
inline ostream   &operator<<(ostream &OutStream, CUInt32 &UInt32Obj)
{
    UInt32Obj.PrintData(OutStream);
    return (OutStream);
}
```

In int main() function I do the following:

```
int main()
{
    CParam *cp = new CUInt32(ANALOG);

    cout << *cp;// Error
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error saying 
**error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << *cp'|**

My questions are

1. Is it possible to use polymorphic base class pointers with cout?
2. If yes, how we could do this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Instead of overloading `operator <<` for `CUInt32`, overload it for `CParam`.

Comment: Not quite sure how I could do this since the second argument of inline ostream   &operator<<(ostream &OutStream, CUInt32 &UInt32Obj) is different for each derived class.

Comment: Also (even though it's not causing problems here) it's good to make it const reference: `inline ostream &operator<<(ostream &OutStream, const CParam& obj)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610986 may help you - it's basically the identical problem

Comment: Suggestion: Change `void PrintData(ostream &OutStream)` to `std::string PrintData () const` and simply use it with `std::cout`, `printf()`, `fprint()`, anywhere you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator is not defined for the base class.
Simply change this:

```
inline ostream   &operator<<(ostream &OutStream, CUInt32 &UInt32Obj)
{
    UInt32Obj.PrintData(OutStream);
    return (OutStream);
}
```

to this:

```
inline ostream   &operator<<(ostream &OutStream, CParam& cParam)
{
    cParam.PrintData(OutStream);
    return (OutStream);
}
```

Basically, defining the `PrintData` in the base class as virtual/abstract ensures it will be available for all subclasses and the correct function will be called.

Answer (score 3):

Along with the obvious point (`operator<<` should take a reference to a const base) you also want to change your definition of `PrintData` to make it a `const`member function, so it can be invoked on a `const` object. The resulting code ends up something like this:

```
struct CParam {
    virtual void PrintData(ostream &OutStream) const = 0;
};

struct CUInt32 : CParam {
    void PrintData(ostream &OutStream) const {}
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &OutStream, CParam const &UInt32Obj) {
    UInt32Obj.PrintData(OutStream);
    return (OutStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since overloading code uses PrintData, you could define the function at base class level itself. Since compiler couldn't find any overloading at base class level, it throws exception.

Comment: So, is it not possible to print the data using base class ptr by no means?

Comment: Then you may have to define a virtual function for that in base