# Polymorphic operator<< from virtual base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I want to overload Operator<< to do a specialized operation within a context of polymorphic classes. To give a direct example of what I want (using int as an example):

```
Base* a = new A;
(*a) << 10;
```

I would like to use this syntax because another portion of my program does the same operation using <<, but on non-polymorphic classes.

The problem is, Base is pure virtual, and I am at a loss how to implement this sort of system without a complete, valid Base class. For example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void aVirtualFunction() = 0;
    virtual Base operator<<( int ) = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
    Base operator<<( int )
    {
        // Do something
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
    Base operator<<( int )
    {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

This generates an error because Base is abstract.

I can't put the overloads in only the inherited classes, as I need to access the operator from a pointer to the base class without casting to a child.

My question is very similar to the question asked in [Overloading << operator with polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917345/overloading-operator-with-polymorphism), except that my base class is not a valid object on its own.

Comment: If you are doing polymorphism it has to be pointers or reference. It cant be by value.

Comment: Since its an abstract class you cannot return by value.

Comment: @Pradheep Yes, I know. I was giving that as an example of what I've tried, and what seems to be the only reasonable way to implement this (even though it doesn't work). What I'd like is some method of setting the operators up that the first example will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as you can't return a `Base` object because it is pure virtual. Return a reference to `Base` instead.

Then, the whole thing is easily handeable using standard inheritance. Consider the following code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void aVirtualFunction() = 0;
    virtual Base& operator<<( int ) = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
    virtual A& operator<<( int ) override
    {
        // Do something
        return *this;
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
    virtual B& operator<<( int ) override
    {
        // Do something
        return *this;
    }
};
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c2791b7d1ead7b2)

Note that the overloads of `operator<<(int)` do not return `Base&`, but rather `A&` and `B&`. This is called *covariance*.

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate the job of `Base::operator<<` to a pure virtual function, which you override in all derived classes, like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
    virtual void delegate(int x) = 0;
public:
    Base& operator<<( int x) // we define this only in Base
    {
        delegate(x); // delegate, this must be overridden in all derived classes
        return *this;
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

void Base::delegate(int x) // we can even define this
{
    std::cout << "Base::delegate x = " << x << std::endl;
}

class A : public Base
{
    void delegate(int x) override
    {
        std::cout << "A::delegate x = " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
    void delegate(int x) override
    {
        std::cout << "B::delegate x = " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> pBase(new B);
    *pBase << 42;
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/114a51f0c939aded)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You should not be returning by value if you want to use polymorphism. You should return by reference.

Note that your `operator<<` was not declared virtual in your base class.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void aVirtualFunction() = 0;
    virtual Base& operator<<( int ) = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
    public:
    A& operator<<( int a)
    {
        // Do something
        a_ = a;
        return *this;
    }

    void aVirtualFunction()
    {
        std::cout << a_ << '\n';
    }

    int a_;
};

class B : public Base
{
    public:
    B& operator<<( int a)
    {
        // Do something
        b_ = a;
        return *this;
    }

    void aVirtualFunction()
    {
        std::cout << b_ << '\n';
    }

    int b_;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    Base* a = new A;
    Base* b = new B;
    *a << 10;
    *b << 11;

    a->aVirtualFunction();
    b->aVirtualFunction();

    delete a;
    delete b;
}
```